# Android apk generator

Tags: android

I am making a book maker app. I searched the net, I haven't found answers to my questions.

My book maker app helps the user to creates new books. I want to save the book as  .APK file and save it in the internal memory. The user should then be able to install it.

I don't know how to generate .APK file from inside an app.  Please help.

Comment: "I haven't found answers to my questions." That is because it is really complicated and the complete answer might fill a book. If you really want to tackle that problem, break it down into really small ones. For example, you should read up on what an apk file is, how the android build tools (you'll kind of need to integrate them into your app) do, how to generate java code, maybe a template engine, ...

Answer (score 1):

Your .APK will contain the reader + book. So when you install the .APK - the book with an embedded reader is installed.

What I would suggest is you do the actual build for the .APK programmaticaly on a server (where there are Java SE or EE, build tools and other tools including the reader) and then download the .APK locally. So that way you can ANT jars on the server.

Here would be the flow -

- the book maker app  creates the book,
- it then sends the book to a server-side app.
- The server side app has access to reader for your book format  (as '`resource`')
- the server also has ANT (or similar build tools) - the build.xml ..
- the server-side app combine the reader and the book (as a resource) -
- it generates the .APK
- sends the .APK to your mobile app

.

The Mobile app receives the .APK and then stores it in the local memory. The .APK is ready for user to install locally. Another benefit of doing it on a server, is that the server can actually cache the .APK created and make it available to others ... remember server side resources are very cheap when compared to the resources available on your mobile phone.

Comment: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.gmail.heagoo.apkcreator

APKCreator working even without internet so there are other ways..